# How do I grab one matching value from an array?

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-maps

I am trying to load a modal with data from a specific map pin that have been tapped.
I render all the markers on the map like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);


...


<MapView
          loadingEnabled={true}
          style={styles.mapView}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          region={{
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
            longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
          }}>
          {
            (markerArr = data.map((listing, index) => (
              <CustomMarker
                key={index}
                image={listing.pin}
                point={listing.point}
                category={listing.categoryID}
                place={listing.place}
                onPress={() => {
                  setModalVisible(true);
                }}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: listing.latitude,
                  longitude: listing.longitude,
                }}
              />
            )))
          }
        </MapView>
```

I then trigger a modal when an individual marker is pressed:

```
<Modal
          style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 10 }}
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
          setModalVisiblity={() => {
            setModalVisible((preState) => (preState = !preState));
          }}>
          <Pressable
            style={{
              margin: 20,
              padding: 5,
              height: 120,
              shadowColor: '#000',
              shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 5,
              },
              shadowOpacity: 0.34,
              shadowRadius: 6.27,

              elevation: 10,
            }}
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
            <Icon name="times-circle" size={20} />
          </Pressable>
          {data.map((listing, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressListingItem(listing)}>
              <MapListing
                key={index}
                name={listing.title}
                image={listing.pin}
                point={listing.point}
                photo={listing.photo}
                category={listing.categoryID}
                description={listing.description}
                place={listing.place}
                style={{
                  margin: 20,
                  padding: 5,
                  height: 120,
                  shadowColor: '#000',
                  shadowOffset: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 5,
                  },
                  shadowOpacity: 0.34,
                  shadowRadius: 6.27,

                  elevation: 10,
                }}
                link={() => {
                  onPressListingItem(listing);
                }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </Modal>
```

Within this modal my `data.map(...` renders all items in the array. I want it to only render the item that matches the pin that triggered it to show. Any help on how to do this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store you selected item in your state as you do with `modalVisible`

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null)

const setSelectedMarker = (marker) => setSelectedMarker(marker)

  
const markerPressed = (marker) => {
  setModalVisible(true);
  setSelectedMarker(marker)
}

...


<MapView
          loadingEnabled={true}
          style={styles.mapView}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          region={{
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
            longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
          }}>
          {
            (markerArr = data.map((listing, index) => (
              <CustomMarker
                key={index}
                image={listing.pin}
                point={listing.point}
                category={listing.categoryID}
                place={listing.place}
                onPress={() => {
                  markerPressed(listing)
                }}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: listing.latitude,
                  longitude: listing.longitude,
                }}
              />
            )))
          }
        </MapView>
```

```js
<Modal
          style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 10 }}
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
          setModalVisiblity={() => {
            setModalVisible((preState) => (preState = !preState));
          }}>
          <Pressable
            style={{
              margin: 20,
              padding: 5,
              height: 120,
              shadowColor: '#000',
              shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 5,
              },
              shadowOpacity: 0.34,
              shadowRadius: 6.27,

              elevation: 10,
            }}
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
            <Icon name="times-circle" size={20} />
          </Pressable>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressListingItem(selectedMarker)}>
              <MapListing
                key={index}
                name={selectedMarker.title}
                image={selectedMarker.pin}
                point={selectedMarker.point}
                photo={selectedMarker.photo}
                category={selectedMarker.categoryID}
                description={selectedMarker.description}
                place={selectedMarker.place}
                style={{
                  margin: 20,
                  padding: 5,
                  height: 120,
                  shadowColor: '#000',
                  shadowOffset: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 5,
                  },
                  shadowOpacity: 0.34,
                  shadowRadius: 6.27,

                  elevation: 10,
                }}
                link={() => {
                  onPressListingItem(selectedMarker);
                }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
```

Comment: Fantastic idea. Always learning, thank you.